# Why does this minimal SDL/OpenGL example work when linking with GL and not OpenGL?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opengl, sdl

With the example code below, it has two different behaviors depending upon if I link with libGL.so vs. [libOpenGL.so](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/glvnd/libglvnd). This is on an Ubuntu 20.04 system with a PCI Radeon GPU. The behavior in both cases is that it will switch video modes. In the "bad/OpenGL" case the glGetString() returns NULL and in the "good/GL case the glGetString() returns a string.

Why does this not work when linking with OpenGL?  When should one link with OpenGL vs GL?

Linking that works: `g++ test.cpp -o testgood -lGL -lGLU -lSDL`

Linking that doesn't work: `g++ test.cpp -o testbad -lOpenGL -lGLU -lSDL`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
    SDL_SetVideoMode( 800, 600, 32, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_FULLSCREEN );

    const unsigned char * tmp = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("CAN'T DETERMINE RENDERER\n"); // Links with OpenGL
        SDL_Quit();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("%s\n", (const char *) tmp); // Links with GL
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: pci express may be?

Comment: I mean discrete GPU not integrated into CPU.  I'm not sure the best term for that.  But yes, probably PCIe, not PCI.

Comment: For the "bad" case does `SDL_SetVideoMode()` return a non-NULL `SDL_Surface*`?  IIRC the linker will silently ignore libraries it can't find; is [`libOpenGL.so`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libopengl-dev) installed?

Comment: libOpenGL.so is installed from the package libopengl-dev.  In both cases I get a non-NULL SDL_Surface.  My full code does error checking on that and the SDL_Init.

Comment: Can't repro on my Kubuntu 20.04 box (discrete [AMD Vega 56](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_RX_Vega_series#RX_Vega_branded_discrete_graphics)), the `-lOpenGL` variant returns a valid `GL_RENDERER`.

Comment: @genpfault, if I remove my AMD GPU driver, then the bad case works.  Do you have the official AMD GPU driver installed?  If so, do you remember the switches you passed to amdgpu-install or amdgpu-pro-install script?

Comment: Just the stock open-source `amdgpu` driver Kubuntu comes with.